# Is there any chance to get it right?

Tags: ios, appium

An unknown *server-side error* occurred while processing the command.

> **Error**: The desired capabilities must include either an app or
>   a bundleId for iOS

I does not accepts *iOS* to platformName and it doesn't let to start session

Comment: Are u uisng firebase make sure to inlcude .plist found in settings

Comment: Can you show your capabilities file so we can see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your **DesiredCapabilites** you must either add (**app** or **bundleId** for ios) or (**app** or **appPackage** and **appActivity** for android).

For Android:

```
  DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
  caps.setCapability("app", "path to apk file");
  //if you don't want to add app capability add following
  caps.setCapability("appPackage", "app package name");
  caps.setCapability("appActivity", "app main activity name");
```

For ios:

```
 DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
 caps.setCapability("app", "path to ipa file");
 //if you don't want to add app capability add bundleId
 caps.setCapability("bundleId", "bundle id of app");
```